# Pandas time series based filtering

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, time-series

Have a time series capturing every second energy consumption ,for a month data ,loaded in pandas dataframe with indexing on timestamp.Trying to develop a code which will spit out the exact duration window in which every second the energy consumtion is > 1500 and the window is nearly 3 hours( it could be ranging somewhere between 2 hr 50 mins to 3 hr 10 mins).This window will occur everyday for a month , so the goal is to capture the exact window time duration for each day

```
                         energy_consumed
timestamp   
2011-08-01 00:00:00-07:00   1322
2011-08-01 00:00:01-07:00   1322
2011-08-01 00:00:02-07:00   1328
2011-08-01 00:00:03-07:00   1328
2011-08-01 00:00:04-07:00   1328
2011-08-01 00:00:05-07:00   1328
2011-08-01 00:00:06-07:00   1328
2011-08-01 00:00:07-07:00   1320
2011-08-01 00:00:08-07:00   1320
2011-08-01 00:00:09-07:00   1320
2011-08-01 00:00:10-07:00   1320
2011-08-01 00:00:11-07:00   1320
2011-08-01 00:00:12-07:00   1320
2011-08-01 00:00:13-07:00   1320
2011-08-01 00:00:14-07:00   1320
2011-08-01 00:00:15-07:00   1320
2011-08-01 00:00:16-07:00   1320
2011-08-01 00:00:17-07:00   1318
2011-08-01 00:00:18-07:00   1318
2011-08-01 00:00:19-07:00   1318
```

Complete data file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qrjaFA6XipIDyEiWOboVghqMh4CEoVj_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can try to iterate through your dataframe and see the continuous appearance of energy_consumed above 1500 and keep an track of count of such continuous rows by maintaining 2 pointers one for start and other to iterate through the rows and finally saving the value of both pointers once you get the desired window.

Comment: While your problem is interesting. It's hard to develop a solution and test it without a sample data. Your given data are neither 3 hours long nor contain any power > 1500. Remember to give sample data as close as your problem description as possible.

Comment: Added the complete dataset link in the post

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using the `.isin()` methond?

It will basically filter your `DataFrame` under a specific value in a list for a column of your choice.

So first you have to get all the values from your `energy_consumed` column that has a value of `>1500` place them all in a list and use that list as argument in the `.isin()` method:

```
energy_greater_than_condition_list = [x for x in df['energy_consumed'].values.tolist() if x > 1500]

df = df.loc[df['energy_consumed'].isin(energy_greater_than_condition_list)]
```

This `df` after executing the above code will now have all the `timestamp` and `energy_consumed` values for `energy_consumed` values of greater than `1500` only.

I hope this helps :)).

Comment: Note: To avoid long calculating time, specially if you have a very long `energy_greater_than_condition_list`, it is best to convert the column you will use for filtering ("energy_consumed" column) as the DataFrame's index. So you might want to declare your original index -  `timestamp` as a column in your DataFrame not its index if the entries for greater than 1500 in the energy_consumed has a big count.